# MATLAB, equationsToMatrix for nonlinear equations

Tags: matlab

After finding equations of motion using the Symbolic Toolbox (R2016b, Windows), I have the following form:

`M(q)*qddot = b(q,qdot) + u`

`M` and `b` were found using `equationsToMatrix`.

Now, I need to separate `b` into Coriolis and Potential terms such that

`M(q)*qddot + C(q,qdot)*qdot + G(q) = u`

It would be extremely convenient if I could apply

`[C,G] = equationsToMatrix(b,qdot)`

but unfortunately it will not factor out `qdot` when `b` is nonlinear. I do not care (and in fact it is necessary) that `C` is a function of `q` and `qdot`, even after factoring out the vector `qdot`. I have tried `coeffs` and `factor` without results.

Thanks.

Comment: You cant. Non-linear means "it can not be described with a matrix". MATLABs `equationsToMatrix` tells you clearly "Convert set of **linear equations** to matrix form"

Comment: I thought that I would attract this kind of comment... I know what the documentation says, I am looking for a workaround or a different function to do what I need. Also, they definitely _can_ be described with a matrix; the matrix just ends up having qdot terms.

Comment: Then its not a numerical matrix, its a variable matrix

Comment: That's fine. How can I solve for it?

Comment: Added a functional solution to the answers. Does exactly what I was asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my own solution so there can be at least one answer...
This function works, but it is not heavily tested. It works exactly as I suggested in my original question. Feel free to rename it so it doesn't conflict with the MATLAB builtin.

```
function [A,b] = equationsToMatrix( eq, x )
%EQUATIONSTOMATRIX equationsToMatrix for nonlinear equations
%   factors out the vector x from eq such that eq = Ax + b
%   eq does not need to be linear in x
%   eq must be a vector of equations, and x must be a vector of symbols

assert(isa(eq,'sym'), 'Equations must be symbolic')
assert(isa(x,'sym'), 'Vector x must be symbolic')

n = numel(eq);
m = numel(x);

A = repmat(sym(0),n,m);

for i = 1:n % loop through equations
    [c,p] = coeffs(eq(i),x); % separate equation into coefficients and powers of x(1)...x(n)
    for k = 1:numel(p) % loop through found powers/coefficients
        for j = 1:m % loop through x(1)...x(n)
            if has(p(k),x(j))
                % transfer term c(k)*p(k) into A, factoring out x(j)
                A(i,j) = A(i,j) + c(k)*p(k)/x(j);
                break % move on to next term c(k+1), p(k+1)
            end
        end
    end
end

b = simplify(eq - A*x,'ignoreanalyticconstraints',true); % makes sure to fully cancel terms

end
```